# PowerPC disassemble with objdump

Tags: objdump, powerpc

I am trying to disassemble PowerPC dump with `objdump`. I have only raw binary dump, not ELF or any other 'container'.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any option to force VLE mode (my binary definitely uses it).

This one is just a short example:

```
~$ objdump -b binary -EB -m powerpc:vle -M vle -D PowerPC_test.bin

PowerPC_test.bin:     file format binary

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
   0:   c5 a9 50 1a     .long 0xc5a9501a
   4:   fb 70 2a a4     .long 0xfb702aa4
```

According to IDA and Ghidra, it should be

```
seg000:00000000 C5 A9                       se_lwz    r26, 0x14(r25)
seg000:00000002 50 1A FB 70                 e_lwz     r0, -0x490(r26)
seg000:00000006 2A A4                       se_cmpi   r4, 0xA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toolchain probably does not support VLE (AFAIK it was never mainlined), so you’ll need a fork with VLE support (e.g. from [Freescale/NXP](https://www.nxp.com/design/software/development-software/s32-design-studio-ide/s32-design-studio-for-power-architecture:S32DS-PA?#design-resources), [Hightec](https://hightec-rt.com/en/products/development-platform) or [ST](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/spc5-studio.html)) and use the toolchain-specific switch to force VLE disassembly

Comment: Yes, you are right. binutils-multiarch doesn't incude it, even though power:vle is in the list of supported architectures. To be honest, it is strange because you can find a lot of PowerPC-related stuff in the binutils sources.
But anyway, objdump from NXP works better, thanks for it.